# how to select years which has more than 2 movies released in mysql

Tags: mysql

My code is :

```
SELECT count(*), title, release_year
FROM film
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 2;`
```

but I got the error: **#2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sakila.film.title**

which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by   0.038 sec

Comment: Remove `title` from the select list.

Comment: Remember, it makes no sense to output the `title` as which one of the 2 or more would you want to pick ? Niether would actually be right!

Comment: Your group by should list all columns that doesn't contain aggregate, columns not listed otherwise get a random (last) value for the group which is very rarely what you want.

Comment: got it thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `title`.
If you are using a group keywords for `x` column, only use **`x`** column name  and **sql functions** like count, min, max, etc in **select** statement.

Answer (score 1):

You want to either group by both title and release_year:

```
SELECT count(*), title, release_year
FROM film
GROUP BY title, release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 2;
```

or just release_year:

```
SELECT count(*), release_year
FROM film
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 2;
```

possible adding `GROUP_CONCAT(title)` to get all titles in for that group in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

To show all tiles the have a count bigger than 2 you can use GROUP _cONCAT and you will not get your error any more

```
SELECT count(*), GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ';'), release_year
FROM film
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 2;`
```